# How to determine if an Element was created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I have an existing system built using jQuery, Backbone.js and a REST-ish back-end written in C#. The application is an SPA with forms to fill and navigation. My job is to build a "Navigation Interceptor" to connect on the application so the system detects whether a field was modified in the current view so that when the user navigates, he will be warned that fields were modified and be requested to save or cancel the changes.

The way I designed it is using jQuery. To make it short, I use a selector on `input`, `select`, etc.. and bind a change event to it. Then I use a selector on links and buttons, unbind all click events, bind my "interceptor" (if a field has changed, ask before navigating) and then rebind all click events after my interceptor. I use `stopImmediatePropagation()` to cancel the regular navigation events, resulting in a kind of wrapper around the events.

By doing so, I have 2 problems:

1. Calling `.val()` on a field does not trigger the change event which is fine since I populate the fields dynamically. The problem is that the bootstrap date pickers does not seem to be setting the value using `.val()` resulting in all date fields having the "changed" state when initialized.
2. Elements dynamically created (e.g.: field in accordion panel created after the page has loaded) don't accept the events resulting in forms not firing the change event of my navigation interceptor.

My question is regarding the 2 above elements:

1. Is there a way to determine if a specific field is a date picker and bind the change event on that field so that when I populate it, the change event does not fire, but when the users do, it does (I tried binding on the `changeDate` event but the `setDate` method seems to be firing the `changeDate` event also)?
2. Is there a way to determine if the element was dynamically created (e.g.: $(''))? The problem is that I do not have a specific selector for a single field, so I think I cannot use delegation (`$(document).on('change', 'someFieldSelectorICannotKnow', function () {});`). All I have is a handle on the jQuery element (`$(this)` in a `.each(fn)` iteration).

**#2 Solved using event delegation on all fields and skipping the handler if the field is not a form field**

*Solution of #2:*

```
NavigationInterceptor.prototype.bindChangeEventOnAllEditableFields = function () {
    var self = this;

    var fieldsSelector = $(this.configuration.selectors.formFields.join(', '));
    $(fieldsSelector).each(function () {
        var isFormField = !self.searchClassFromArrayInElement(self.configuration.classes.nonFormFieldClasses, $(this));

        if (isFormField && self.configuration.debug.highlight.fields.unchanged && $(this).attr('type') === 'radio') {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', self.configuration.debug.highlight.fields.unchanged);
        } else if (isFormField && self.configuration.debug.highlight.fields.unchanged) {
            $(this).css('background-color', self.configuration.debug.highlight.fields.unchanged);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('change', fieldsSelector, function (event) {
        var field = $(event.target);
        var isFormField = !self.searchClassFromArrayInElement(self.configuration.classes.nonFormFieldClasses, field);

        if (isFormField) {
            self.hasFieldChanged = true;

            if (self.configuration.debug.highlight.fields.changed) {
                if (field.attr('type') === 'radio') {
                    field.parent().css('background-color', self.configuration.debug.highlight.fields.changed);
                } else {
                    field.css('background-color', self.configuration.debug.highlight.fields.changed);
                }
            }
        }
    });


    return this;
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd try to figure out how to store the initial data model on page load, and then when the user navigates compare that to the current model. Forget about tracking _how_ it changed. Seems simpler.

Comment: Hey @jszobody, doing so would require me to change all backbone views, their initialization functions and navigation functions. Data model is set on the initialization of the view. Moreover, the navigation is done in each views and, sometimes, from other views (e.g.: A view containing a tabbed navigation is split different tabs and wrapped in a another view containing only the navigation). Time drives this projet, we're already late :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var unchangeable_classes = ['decorative', 'constant'];
$(document).on('change', 'input,select,textarea', function () {
    var $this=$(this); 
    for(var i =0;i<unchangeable_classes.length;++i){
       if($this.hasClass(unchangeable_classes[i]))
           return;
    } 
    global_changed = true;
});
```

Why doesn't this work, it should? (Edited in response to comment.)

Comment: It does indeed work, though I made that interceptor configurable. I need to filter out specific elements. For example, there is a date field on an agenda that can change, but it's not saved. So, the interceptor has a list of css classes that, when added to the field, it will be considered as a non-form field and the change event will not be fired for navigation protection. What would you recommend?

Comment: See my edits to the question. I wanted to keep track of the form fields so I can rebind the event on newly created fields. Are you suggesting I should not track? This piece of code is the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok... I see. You're proposing to bind the change event on everything and skip the execution in case the field is not a form field. That's actually interesting.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but `this` inside the function makes reference to the `document` object. Any idea?

Comment: `var field = $(event.target);` THANKS! That works! All I need is the datepicker problem :)

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts>>

1)A way to stop calling changeDate() after calling setDate(), you could just call `event.stopPropogation()`, it will prevent the event from bubbling up

2)while creating a dynamic element, you could add any property of your wish. For eg

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.isDynamic = true;
```

then while iterating through the element, check for isDynamic property

Comment: `view.find('.h-ArrivedDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(employee.arrivedDate));` does not allow to add stopPropagation unless I modifiy bootstrap's code, which I don't want :)

Regarding the flag, there would be too many places to change and the risk of someone forgetting to manually add that flag each time a field is generated is to high for us.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a benign class tag to the element

```
$('#foo').addClass('bar');
```

then you can check for the class to see if it was created

```
if ($('#foo').hasClass('bar'))
    alert('was created');
```

Note that when you add elements you have to re-attach the events. So if you have a global document event and then add an element, that element won't be included unless you explicitly attach the new element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer for my question #1.

What I did is modify bootstrap's source. When calling `setDate` like so:

```
$('#myDateInput').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

The code goes through the function `setDates` which calls `update` and `setValue`, the first one resulting in the date being set in the datepicker itself, the second one setting only the value in the input text field. What I did is remove the call to 'change' which triggers the change event on the field and left the custom event 'dateChange'. This results in my code not firing the change event when I call `setDate`, but calls it when the user sets a date using the picker itself.